# Is there any reason why the command line in Windows7 would open and close without my interaction

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I am using a Dell Inspiron N4050 with Windows 7. Today while working in Open Office I saw the command line window open a for a brief second, too quick to read, and close again. It was so fast I thought I had imagined it, it was like a quick black rectangle appearing and vanishing. Then a few seconds later it opened and closed again, this time long enough for me to see it was the command line window, but still too fast to read.

I had nothing installing or updating at the time, that I know of. I was downloading an update for Open Office, but was downloading only, not running it and it was only 20% done with the download anyway.

I run Macafee NetProtect plus and it has detected nothing

I am concerned maybe my system was just compromised but as I am new to Windows 7 I thought I should ask if this was a normal occurrence before jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when a commandline program is executed, it will open a cmd window, run, and then the window will close once the program has finished executing. If you try running CLI programs (such as dir) from the GUI, you will get this.

Probably just a background script doing some maintenance - but perhaps worth running a virus scan just to be safe.

Comment: What is 'dir'?  I am not familiar with that

Comment: `dir` is used to list files in the current directory from the command line. It was just given as an example of a common CLI tool.